# Pandas: Is Series homogenous?

Tags: python, pandas, series

Is Pandas Series homogenous or heterogeneous?

```
import pandas as pd
S=pd.Series([1,2,3,1.5,'US',True,False,'India'])
>>> S
0        1
1        2
2        3
3      1.5
4       US
5     True
6    False
7    India
dtype: object
>>> S[3]
1.5
>>> type(S[5])
<class 'bool'>
```

Comment: Homogenous. That Series is of dtype `object`. And everything in there is a subtype of object (since everything in python is a subtype of object).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Homogeneous data and Heterogeneous data?](/q/31277709/4518341) (I know it's tagged [tag:sql], but the same thing applies to Pandas)

Comment: I'd say heterogeneous because there are different data types there, str, int, float, and bool, however the argument certainly exists that it is heterogeneous in the fact that all the entries are objects.

Comment: but it is showing that it is heterogeneous as it can accept any datatype just like dataframes in pandas?

Comment: What is showing?

Comment: @Henry By that definition, no data is heterogeneous in Python. Is that true?

Comment: @wjandrea in python you could have a list `[1, 'a', 6.2]` which contains different types and is heterogenous. In numpy and pandas that is converted into a structure of dtype object, while in python the python example the list itself does not have a type (it's just `list`) only the contained elements have types. The key difference being that you can add something to the list without reallocating the structure, where introducing new values to a Series might force the dtype of the Series to change. Which is different than the dynamically typed python structures.

Comment: @Henry Gotcha, the Series itself is homogeneous (a Series must be by definition). But the data it references is heterogeneous since it's of different types, right?

Comment: @wjandrea I believe that is correct insofar as Series must have exactly one dtype (even if that dtype is `object`). Unfortunately (as you noted above) semantically dtype `object` is difficult as there really isn't anything in python that you couldn't put into a container of objects since (almost) everything is an object.

Comment: Depends entirely on how you define 'homogeneous'; this is pedantic. If you execute `s = pd.Series([1,2.2,8])` then`s = pd.Series([1,2.2,s,8])` all the elements are dtype 'object', but element 2 is a reference to the series, whereas the others are integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition and documentation Series are homogenous.

[Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) are defined as:

> One-dimensional **ndarray** with axis labels (including time series).

[ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) are defined as:

> An array object represents a multidimensional, **homogeneous** array of fixed-size items.

(bolding mine in both quotes)

Series of dtype `object`, however, are tricky. Since virtually everything in python can be considered an `object`, a huge amount of different types of variables can be referenced by this kind of Series. So while the Series itself is a **homogenous collection of references to objects**, those individual objects when referenced may have heterogenous subtypes.

Accessing each individual value from the Series will result in their individual types being exposed, however, we *only* have a guarantee that all of the elements in the Series will be of type `object`.

---

We most commonly get Series of dtype `object` either when working strings, or when pulling rows from fragmented DataFrames.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
    'C': [3.4, 5.6, 7.8]
})

s1 = df['B']
s2 = df.iloc[0, :]
```

`s1` (Column B):

```
0    x
1    y
2    z
Name: B, dtype: object
```

`s2` (Row 0):

```
A      1
B      x
C    3.4
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

We can see that pandas cannot determine the difference between a string column of dtype `object` and a column containing mixed types of dtype `object` by using a method like [`Series.str.upper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.upper.html):

```
s1.str.upper()

0    X
1    Y
2    Z
Name: B, dtype: object
```

```
s2.str.upper()

A    NaN
B      X
C    NaN
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Notice that (in pandas 1.3.5) the numeric (`int` and `float`) values have been turned into `NaN`. This does not raise any Error or Warning.

(This also works for the provided sample Series)

```
pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 1.5, 'US', True, False, 'India']).str.upper()

0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      NaN
4       US
5      NaN
6      NaN
7    INDIA
dtype: object
```

Again, this is due to the fact that pandas sees this Series as a homogeneous collection of objects, which allows for the use of the dtype restricted `.str` methods.